# Kendo MVC DropDownListFor binding issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to Kendo MVC, so please bear with me.
I have the following code to create a Kendo MVC DropDownListFor:

```
                 @(Html.Kendo()
                    .DropDownListFor(m => m.PrimaryId.Kind)
                    .SelectedIndex(-1)
                    .OptionLabel("Choose identification kind")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:100%", @required = "true" })
                    .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
                    .MinLength(1)
                    .DataTextField("Literal")
                    .DataValueField("Code")
                    .DataSource(source => source
                        .Read(read => read
                            .Url(AdminConfiguration.AdminAPIUrl
                                + "/classification/v1/classification-values/getClassificationValues?apiId=party&schemaId=identification-kind")
                            .Type(HttpVerbs.Get)
                        )
                        .ServerFiltering(true)
                    )
                )
```

The "PrimaryId.Kind" property of the ViewModel is correspondent to the "Code" property
of the data received from the DataSource - Read endpoint.

The generated output is actually a dropdownlist AND a label for the actual value selected
(it makes me think that the binding went wrong).[image]

Please advise.

Thank you,
Octavian

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
It has to do with the fact that a nested property was used to bind the DropDown.
It sounds weird, but this is how I fixed:

I created a property wrapper for the nested property:

```
    public string PersonalIdKindWrapper 
    {
        get
        {
            return PrimaryId.Kind;
        }
        set
        {
            PrimaryId.Kind = value;
        }
    }
```

Then, in the view, I used the wrapper property :

```
   @(Html.Kendo()
         .DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonalIdKindWrapper)
         ………….
```

Happy coding !   :)